# Algorithm question: Given a binary array, find the maximum length of a contiguous subarray with equal number of 0 and 1

Tags: algorithms, hash-tables, algorithm-design

Algorithm question:

> Given a binary array, find the maximum length of a contiguous subarray with equal number of 0 and 1.
>
> Example 1:
> Input: [0,1] Output: 2
> Explanation: [0, 1] is the longest contiguous subarray with equal number of 0 and 1.
>
> Example 2:
> Input: [0,1,0] Output: 2
> Explanation: [0, 1] (or [1, 0]) is a longest contiguous subarray with equal number of 0 and 1.

Original source: https://leetcode.com/problems/contiguous-array/

This question reminded me of prefix-sum questions i had done before.
Given array nums:

```
sum(nums[0:i]) + sum(nums[i:j]) = sum(nums[0:j])
```

So I figured:

```
Assuming 2*sum(nums[i:j]) =  len(nums[i:j])-> always True for valid subarrays,

2sum(i:j) = 2(sum(0:j)- sum(0:i))

(j-i+1) = 2(sum(0:j)- sum(0:i))

-i+2sum(0:i) +1 = 2sum(0:j)-j
```

But it looks like Im having trouble with the code assuming this. I was excited to separate the `i` and the `j` (indexes) so that i can hash like so:

```
        key: -i+2sum(0:i) +1,      value: i
        check for the key with our j value later, 
        then do j-i+1
        then compare that to a running global max.
```

Code:

```
        d = {}
        sum = 0
        m = 0
        for j in range(len(nums)):
            sum += nums[j]
            if 2*sum - j in d:
                i = d[2*sum - j]
                m = max(m,j-i+1)
            if 2*sum-j+1 not in d:
                d[2*sum-j+1] = j
        return m
```

It does not work on this input:

```
[1,0,0,1,1,0]-> output is 4 instead of 6
```

I think there might be some sort of indexing issue.

Comment: You seem to have created multiple accounts.  I encourage you to merge them: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  This will ensure you keep full access to your question.

Comment: Coding and implementation questions are off-topic here.  Debugging your code and tracking down indexing bugs are off-topic here.  If you have a question about algorithms, I encourage you to replace the code with concise pseudocode.  Please don't use code blocks (`..`) for indenting or emphasis; that can be hard to read.  Can you tell us the context where you encountered this task, and credit the original source of all copied material?

Comment: Your idea is sound, hence the problem must be with the implementation. The task will be less confusing if you switch from $0,1$ to $\pm 1$. Now you are looking for *identical* prefix sums.